# How to use SQL variable to iterate XML nodes

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have this XML in SQL Server 2008:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<Root>
                      <Contacts>
                        <Contact name="John Doe" type="REG" other="value" />
                        <Contact name="Jane Doe" type="REG" other="value" />
                        <Contact name="Jennifer Doe" type="REG" other="value" />
                        <Contact name="Jane Doe" type="REG" other="value" />
                      </Contacts>
                    </Root>'
```

I want to change the value of the types to something else. I can hard code which one(s) I want to change with no problem.

```
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Root/Contacts/Contact)[1]/@type with "NEW"')
SELECT @xml
```

That "does the right thing," regardless of what value I put in the brackets. IOW, the above changes the first one, changing it to [3] changes the third one, etc.

I want to change all of them, regardless of how many or how few there are. So, I need to get the count, then iterate over them using a variable. Getting the count is easy, but I can't get the variable to work.

IOW, this XML, which just replaces the [1] above with the variable, doesn't work.

```
DECLARE @i int = 1
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Root/Contacts/Contact)[sql:variable("@i")]/@type with "NEW"')
SELECT @xml
```

It gives me this error, which is telling me I did something wrong, but I can't grok the error to figure out *what* I did wrong:

> Msg 2337, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   XQuery [modify()]: The target of 'replace' must be at most one node, found 'attribute(type,xdt:untypedAtomic) *'

As I was about to hit "Post" on this, I found reference to something that said you had to use position() in order to use a variable on the node index, but the example was a query, not a modify. And that doesn't work, either.

```
DECLARE @i int = 1
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Root/Contacts/Contact)[position()=sql:variable("@i")]/@type with "NEW"')
SELECT @xml
```

I have no doubt this is something easy, but I've searched here and elsewhere for how to use `sql:variable`, and almost all of the examples I've found are using it as the value in a replace, not the index (none of the "Questions which may already have your answer" helped, either.) I've also experimented with extra parentheses in various places, etc., and just haven't been able to hit on the magic combination.

What am I missing to make the above SET work with @i?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your own code would work with just one more `[1]`. The function `.modify()` cannot interpret the `[sql:variable(...)]`... This might be any filter, even one with more than one result... So just change this to:

```
DECLARE @xml xml = '<Root>
                      <Contacts>
                        <Contact name="John Doe" type="REG" other="value" />
                        <Contact name="Jane Doe" type="REG" other="value" />
                        <Contact name="Jennifer Doe" type="REG" other="value" />
                        <Contact name="Jane Doe" type="REG" other="value" />
                      </Contacts>
                    </Root>';
DECLARE @i int = 1
SET @xml.modify('replace value of (/Root/Contacts/Contact)[sql:variable("@i")][1]/@type with "NEW"')
SELECT @xml
```

But I would go another path... You might read the whole lot as derived table and rebuild the XML like this:

```
SELECT
(
    SELECT c.value('@name','nvarchar(max)') AS [@name]
          --,c.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS [@type]
          ,'NEW' AS [@type]
          ,c.value('@other','nvarchar(max)') AS [@other]
    FROM @xml.nodes('/Root/Contacts/Contact') AS A(c)
    FOR XML PATH('Contact'),ROOT('Contact'),TYPE
)
FOR XML PATH('Root')
```

Another approach would be FLWOR:

```
SELECT @xml.query('
for $r in /Root/Contacts
    return <Root><Contacts>
    {
        for $c in /Root/Contacts/Contact
           return <Contact name="{$c/@name}" type="NEW" other="{$c/@other}"/>
    }
    </Contacts></Root>
')
```

Comment: Well, that works, but I'll be durned if I understand _why_ it works. :) The variable is acting as the index (it's in brackets). Why do I need _another_ index? (Mostly rhetorical; it works, so I'll use it, I just won't understand it.)
The derived table would get messy; the actual XML is a lot more complicated, with a lot more parent/child nodes like Contacts. I just need one attribute of one set of nodes in the multi-parent node XML changed, so I think iterating over just those nodes is easiest. Thanks!

Comment: @vr8ce, It's not so difficult: The square brackets allow you to place an `XQuery`-filter. You might, e.g., filter for all `Contact`-elements like `/Root/Contacts/Contact[@name="Jane Doe"]`. This would - in your example - return two rows. But the literal number is one clear position. With `.modifiy()` the engine must be sure, that this will affect one single node only. In other words: *Find **all elements** at the position of the variable and then take the first of this set* (funny for us, but not for the engine...)