# How to find all parent node by a value in child node with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to XML queries in SQL Server. I would like write a query that

1. Finds a value in child node and to remove its parent node
2. Re-orders items order in child node

As my example below: my column's type is `nvarchar(max)` and stores value:

```
<Trainings>
    <Training>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <Data>test1</Data>
        <ItemOrder>1</ItemOrder>
    </Training> 
    <Training>
        <Id>12</Id>
        <Data>test12</Data>
        <ItemOrder>2</ItemOrder>
    </Training>
    <Training>
        <Id>101</Id>
        <Data>test111</Data>
        <ItemOrder>3</ItemOrder>
    </Training> 
    <Training>
        <Id>102</Id>
        <Data>test122</Data>
        <ItemOrder>4</ItemOrder>
    </Training> 
</Trainings>
```

The expected result must be:

```
<Trainings>
    <Training>
        <Id>10</Id>
        <Data>test1</Data>
        <ItemOrder>1</ItemOrder>
    </Training> 
    <Training>
        <Id>101</Id>
        <Data>test111</Data>
        <ItemOrder>2</ItemOrder>
    </Training> 
    <Training>
        <Id>102</Id>
        <Data>test122</Data>
        <ItemOrder>3</ItemOrder>
    </Training> 
</Trainings>
```

I've tried with the query as below but how can I find the `Training` node number with `test12` in `Data` child? and then reorder all `ItemOrder` for all `Training` nodes.

```
CREATE TABLE Resume ([Training] nvarchar(max));

INSERT INTO Resume ([Training])
VALUES ('<Trainings><Training><Id>10</Id><Data>test1</Data><ItemOrder>1</ItemOrder></Training><Training><Id>12</Id><Data>test12</Data><ItemOrder>2</ItemOrder></Training><Training><Id>101</Id><Data>test111</Data><ItemOrder>3</ItemOrder></Training><Training><Id>102</Id><Data>test122</Data><ItemOrder>4</ItemOrder></Training></Trainings>');

DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @string = [Training] 
FROM Resume

DECLARE @xml XML

SET @xml = CONVERT(XML, @string)
SET @xml.modify('delete (/Trainings/Training)[2]')
SET @string = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @xml)

SELECT @string
```

Here is the **Fiddle** link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/894a0/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use XPath with the predicate you search

```
set @xml.modify('delete (/Trainings/Training[./Data = "test12"])')
```

UPDATE: in order to solve also the second issue I propose to use a completely different XML-relational approach:

```
SELECT c.value('(./Id/node())[1]','int') AS Id,
       c.value('(./Data/node())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Data,
       row_number() over (order by c.value('(./Id/node())[1]','int')) as ItemOrder
FROM @xml.nodes('/Trainings/Training') AS A(c)
WHERE c.value('(./Data/node())[1]','nvarchar(max)') != 'test12'
FOR XML PATH('Training'),ROOT('Trainings'),TYPE
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/894a0/76)

Comment: As I've tested, your query worked well to remove the `Training` node by `test12` as my first point. In my view, that is great because of a simple query but it gets the best performance? Do you have any idea for the second point?

Comment: @HuyDQ sorry, I did not notice the second point. It will be quite tricky. My idea is to derive a relational table, add new column having the proper counting, and then extract the XML again ...

Comment: @HuyDQ something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39709430/how-to-use-sql-variable-to-iterate-xml-nodes

Comment: That would be a good idea. However, it is impossible to add a new column :(. I mean that you have any idea to write the query for the second point?

Comment: @HuyDQ the point is to replace the `ItemOrder` column with a new one with data you need. No, I do not know how to write it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to send you a vote up for the first point. Please get back if you have any new idea for the second one.

Comment: That's awesome. It works as my expectation even I do not understand it too much with `./Id/node())[1]` (**`[1]`**) and `FOR XML PATH('Training'),ROOT('Trainings'),TYPE` :-(